# Sonata admin bundle email validation

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

What is the best way to add an email validation in Sonata Admin?

I saw a discussion in Google groups about it and it says:

"Why force developers to repeat all validation constraints twice?"

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sonata-users/xO64f_haMks

Is that true? Or is there a way to use the Symfony2 Validation at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works like this:

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
            ->add('email', 'email')
```

Comment: That only says 'use the `<input type="email" />` HTML5 tag to render the email field'. It does not provide any server side validation of the email address and is not a valid solution. You also need to set up validation on the underlying object.

Comment: i try same thing but in Textbox I not able to press @ key for emailid ,

Below is Code  that generate after add email field in form mapper

<input type="email" id="s5a423ea92b124_email" name="s5a423ea92b124[email]" required="required" class="form-control form-control" data-placeholder="emailid">

Anything I missing?